# jQuery tooltip is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I want a tooltip to show when I rollover on particular links. It's not working. The commented out alert is working, so event is not the issue. This is my javascript code:

```
$(window).load( function() {

$("a").each(function() {
    if(this.text==" View image") {

        $(this).mouseover(function() {
//              alert("blabla");
            $(this).tooltip();
        });

    }

});
```

});

on my html file the includes are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.tooltip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="mainscript.js"></script>
```

I'd appreciate some help.

UPDATE: removing mouseover doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

Remove the mouseover function. The plugin doesn't require you to add a custom mouseover function. It's done from the plugin for you.

```
if(this.text==" View image") {
            $(this).tooltip();
    }
```

Hope this helps ^^

Change the main jQuery function to $(document).ready(function(){});

This will probably work now~

Comment: To find more ways to use this plugin refer the demos - http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if(this.innerHTML == " View image") {
        $(this).tooltip();
    }
}
```

Also, there's a space before the View in "View image". I'm not sure if that's intentional or not.

Answer (score 0):

I used [jQuery tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) on my recent projects. Quite easy to understand and integrate.