# jQuery not working in body of Angular app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm using jQuery to load gapi (so my app has the ability to log a user out using their Google+ account). I've loaded jQuery in the head of my index.html, but it doesn't seem to be getting picked up as I get the following error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function`.

This is the script I'm attempting to run at the end of my body:

```
  <script>
    (function() {
      $('#button-address').tooltip();
      var po = document.createElement('script');
      po.type = 'text/javascript';
      po.async = true;
      po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
  </script>
</body>
```

and in the head:

```
<script src='../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: If jQuery weren't loaded, I would think it would error on `$()` instead of on `tooltip()`. So perhaps that error is correct, and `tooltip is not a function`

Comment: Is your reference before angular?

Comment: not loaded the jquery ui or ui-bootstrap js

Answer (score 0):

`tooltip()` is a  part of jQuery UI not the core jQuery library.

Include the script for jQuery UI (along with jQuery)

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

SO have lot of answer for this same issue

[.tooltip() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394390/tooltip-is-not-a-function)

[TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279789/typeerror-tooltip-is-not-a-function)

[jQuery tooltip is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940864/jquery-tooltip-is-not-working)

[$(...).tooltip is not working since jQuery 1.9.2 is not working due to old jQuery UI 1.8.16 library? How to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024304/tooltip-is-not-working-since-jquery-1-9-2-is-not-working-due-to-old-jquer)

[How to add and show a Bootstrap tooltip inside a jQuery click function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405583/how-to-add-and-show-a-bootstrap-tooltip-inside-a-jquery-click-function)

More Details for [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.tooltip%28%29%20is%20not%20a%20function)